# renderDisplayFunc in opengl/glut is calling myfunc more than once

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

```
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define XWidth 700  // Clipping window size 700*700
#define YHeight 700 

void renderFunction() {

/*Clear Information from last draw
Sets the current clearing color for use in clearing
color buffers in RGBA mode.
*/
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Set line width
    glLineWidth(1);

    //(x,y) coordinates as in pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, XWidth, 0, YHeight, -1, 1);


    //Set line color
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //random num generated
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    int r1 = rand() % 1000;
    int r2 = rand() % 1000;
    int r3 = rand() % 1000;
    int r4 = rand() % 1000;

    //Begin LINE coordinates
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2d(r1, r2);
        glVertex2d(r3,r4);
    //End LINE coordinate
    glEnd();
    cout<<r1<<" "<<r2<<" "<<r3<<" "<<r4<<" i is "<<i<<endl;}

    //Forces previously issued OpenGL commands to begin execution
    glFlush();
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);

    //Set Output Window Size
    glutInitWindowSize(XWidth,YHeight);

    //Set the position of Output window corresponding to Screen
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

    //Create the Window
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL - Classify line among three classes");

    //Set handler functions for drawing
    glutDisplayFunc(renderFunction);

    //Start the main loop
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm executing the above program, it's working fine. But the issue is that when I'm printing the values of randomly generated variables `r1` `r2` `r3` `r4`, they are being printed 8 or sometimes 12 times. It means `glutDisplayFunc(renderFunction);` is calling `renderFunction` more than once which is not required.

How to control this behavior. I want `renderFunction` to be called just once.

**UPDATE**: I want 4 lines to be created and exactly 4 Lines are being formed but when I'm printing the coordinates, they are showing unexpected behavior as I mentioned above.

Comment: Does `rand()` give you the same set of 4 values 8 or 12 times in a row?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting 4 set of values but as you can see I'm also drawing lines using these values, lines are limited(4 or less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems I see here.

The smaller one is that your indentation of the for loop within the `renderFunction` is a bit misleading. There will always be exactly 4 iterations of that loop, each printing the random variables once.

The second one is that you appear to misunderstand the meaning of `glutDisplayFunc(renderFunction);`. As explained  [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html), this only registers `renderFunction` as the default "display" callback for glut, and also:

> GLUT determines when the display callback should be triggered based on the window's redisplay state.

[`glutMainLoop`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node14.html) will call the registered callbacks until the program finishes. Note that `glutMainLoop` never returns. The program is interrupted either by an unhandled signal or by the closing of the main window. This means that if you minimize and restore the window, glut will want to repaint its contents and will call the display callback (`renderFunction`) again.

Since you cannot easily control, or should not attempt to control  when glut calls the display function, I would suggest that you make sure that the display function will only paint to the screen. You can generate (and print) the random values in your `main` function and have the random variables be global so that they are easily accessible from `renderFunction`. Alternatively, guard the execution of the sampling and that of the printing by a conditional statement which modifies a flag upon first execution:

```
// at global scope (before renderFunction)
generated = false
declare random variables
...
// inside renderFunction 
if (generated = false) {
  generate RV
  print RV
  generated = true
}
display lines
```

In either case, you will need to store all 16 random variables, since you generate 4 random values 4 times (and you use all of them for drawing/prnting). I would suggest storing them in an `int r[4][4];`

Here is my preferred version:

```
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define XWidth 700  // Clipping window size 700*700
#define YHeight 700 

int r[4][4];

void renderFunction() {

  /*Clear Information from last draw
    Sets the current clearing color for use in clearing
    color buffers in RGBA mode.
   */
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  //Set line width
  glLineWidth(1);

  //(x,y) coordinates as in pixels
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0, XWidth, 0, YHeight, -1, 1);

  //Set line color
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  //random num generated
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    //Begin LINE coordinates
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(r[i][0], r[i][1]);
    glVertex2d(r[i][2], r[i][3]);
    //End LINE coordinate
    glEnd();
  }

  //Forces previously issued OpenGL commands to begin execution
  glFlush();
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  //Initialize GLUT
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);

  //Set Output Window Size
  glutInitWindowSize(XWidth,YHeight);

  //Set the position of Output window corresponding to Screen
  glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

  //Create the Window
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL - Classify line among three classes");

  //Set handler functions for drawing
  glutDisplayFunc(renderFunction);

  //random num generated
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    r[i][0] = rand() % 1000;
    r[i][1] = rand() % 1000;
    r[i][2] = rand() % 1000;
    r[i][3] = rand() % 1000;

    cout<<r[i][0] << " " << r[i][1]<<" "<<r[i][2]<<" "<<r[i][3]<<" i is "<<i<<endl;
  }

  //Start the main loop
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**
An interesting twist to the problem was proposed in the comments section by the original poster. I will paraphrase it here:

> If you require a large (10000+) number of lines and memory is a huge concern, can we still    get the originally desired behavior:random values printed only once and lines not changing position every time the screen gets repainted.

The answer is: yes! One way of keeping the very low memory footprint you originally had is by using a combination of the "if" guard trick for printing and generating the (same) random values every time by [re-seeding the random number generator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

```
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define XWidth 700  // Clipping window size 700*700
#define YHeight 700

bool printed;
int random_seed;

void renderFunction() {

  /*Clear Information from last draw
    Sets the current clearing color for use in clearing
    color buffers in RGBA mode.
   */
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  //Set line width
  glLineWidth(1);

  //(x,y) coordinates as in pixels
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0, XWidth, 0, YHeight, -1, 1);


  //Set line color
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);


  // =============================================
  // set the seed of your random number generator
  // ---------------------------------------------
  srand(random_seed);
  // =============================================

  //random num generated
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    int r1 = rand() % 1000;
    int r2 = rand() % 1000;
    int r3 = rand() % 1000;
    int r4 = rand() % 1000;

    //Begin LINE coordinates
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(r1, r2);
    glVertex2d(r3,r4);
    //End LINE coordinate
    glEnd();

    // ***********************************************
    // make sure the values are only printed the first
    // time around
    // ***********************************************
    if (!printed) {
      cout<<r1<<" "<<r2<<" "<<r3<<" "<<r4<<" i is "<<i<<endl;
    }
  }

  printed = true;

  //Forces previously issued OpenGL commands to begin execution
  glFlush();
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  //Initialize GLUT
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);

  //Set Output Window Size
  glutInitWindowSize(XWidth,YHeight);

  //Set the position of Output window corresponding to Screen
  glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

  //Create the Window
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL - Classify line among three classes");

  //Set handler functions for drawing
  glutDisplayFunc(renderFunction);


  // =======================================
  // generate a random seed for the lines
  // ---------------------------------------
  srand(time(0));
  random_seed = rand();
  // =======================================

  // ==========================================
  // initialize the printing guard to "false",
  // i.e. "did not print the random values yet"
  // ------------------------------------------
  printed = false;
  // ==========================================


  //Start the main loop
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this method is **very** similar to the code in the original question, with added code clearly delimited using comments. The up side is that it uses a constant amount of memory regardless of the number of lines you want to draw. The down side is that calling `rand()` is a bit expensive, so you get the usual trade-off between high speed (the former version) and low memory consumption (this latter version).

Comment: what if i have to generate 10000+ lines. It would require a huge amount of memory for array.

Comment: @VarunMalhotra This memory constraint is not really the initial issue, but it is a good point. I will provide an alternative for that.